# ArcPy Error : Input raster: is not the type of Composite Geodataset, or does not exist

Tags: arcpy, netcdf, error-000860

Below is a script I am working on to extract time series NetCDF to raster. The script is working fine without mask layer. When I tried to assign a mask file to extract ROI before I save it to tiff, it fails with a 000860 error.

```py
for dimension in nc_Dim:
        if dimension == "time":
            top = nc_FP.getDimensionSize(dimension)
            for i in range(0, top):

                dimension_values = nc_FP.getDimensionValue(dimension, i)
                nowFile = str(dimension_values)
                nowFile = nowFile.translate(None, '/')

                if int(nowFile[-4:]) == 2005:

                    dv1 = ["time", dimension_values]
                    dimension_values = [dv1]

                    NetCDF = arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(inNetCDF, variable, x_dimension, y_dimension, nowFile, band_dimension, dimension_values, valueSelectionMethod)
                    print "success"
                    outname = outLoc + nowFile
                    mask = "D:\data\NEW.shp" #(1)
                    maskdata = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask (mask, nowFile) #(2)
                    ##after executing line 1 and 2 its shows below error. 

                    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(maskdata, outname + ".tif", "", "", "", "NONE", "NONE", "")

                    print outLoc, outname
```

Error Messgae :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 40, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7051, in ExtractByMask
    in_mask_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 7047, in Wrapper
    out_raster)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 504, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000860: Input raster: is not the type of Composite Geodataset, or does not exist.
Failed to execute (ExtractByMask).
```

Comment: You try `mask = "D:/data/NEW.shp"` ?

Comment: yes, I trying to extract region of interest before save it in raster format

Comment: @SWAT `mask = "D:\data\NEW.shp"` is an invalid path for python.  It needs to be `mask = "D:/data/NEW.shp"` as Richard suggested above, or `mask = r"D:\data\NEW.shp"`

Comment: i have updated the line by adding r but its producing same error

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple case of not reading the help file. If you look at the [syntax section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm#GUID-C14848CD-0636-4F50-85FE-A6B898664131) what is the first parameter for this tool? Now look at your code, what have you provided as the first parameter? Is it a Raster Layer as the syntax section specifies...?

Also, `nowFile` is not a raster layer.

So the following should work:

```
maskdata = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask (NetCDF, mask)
```

Then you now have a `Raster` object which has a `save` method, so no need for `arcpy.CopyRaster_management`

```
maskdata.save(outname + ".tif")
```